# Webpack & Babel-Loader - Unexpected Token on Object Rest Operator, with transform-object-rest-spread Plugin Installed

Tags: webpack, vue.js, babeljs

I'm attempting to create a simple VueJS project, and am having trouble following one of the example instructions given in the Vuex documentation. I've created a Vuex module to encapsulate the state for one module of the application like so:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        namespaced: true,
        state: {
            created: false,
            // Other variables...
        },
        mutations: {
            CREATE(state) {
                state.app.created = true;
            }
        },
        actions: {
            createCampaign({ commit }) {
                commit('app/CREATE');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I then attempt to use the `actions` defined above in one of my Vue components:

```
<template>
    <!-- HTML -->
</template>

<script>
    import { mapActions } from 'vuex';

    let methods = { 
        ...mapActions('app', {
            create: 'createCampaign'
        })
    };

    export default {
        // data, computed...
        methods
    }
</script>
```

It should then be bundled up by Webpack and compiled using Babel, using the following configuration:

```
const javascriptRule = {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
            presets: ['es2015'],
            plugins: [ 'transform-object-rest-spread' ]
        }
    }]
};

const vueRule = {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader'
};

module.exports = {
    entry: /* app entry... */,

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [javascriptRule, vueRule, /* other rules... */]
    },

    // Plugins, other things...
};
```

However, when I build the application, I'm getting the following error message:

```
Unexpected token:
...mapActions('app', {
^
    create: 'createCampaign'
})
```

Am I missing something from my Webpack configuration? I know that the spread operator was recently removed from the `stage-2` preset, so I figured that I'd manually add in the spread operator as a plugin.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: How your vue-loader configuration looks like ?

Comment: I've updated my original question with the vue-loader config.

Comment: Okay, I'd suggest you to move your babel related things from webpack.config to separated `.babelrc` file in project root.So your .babelrc file should looks like this `{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}`

Comment: That seems to have done it! Looking through the [ES2015](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/es2015.html) documentation for `vue-loader`, it states that it'll detect the presence of BabelJS and use that. However, it wasn't picking up the Babel configuration settings within the Webpack config file. Extracting them out into `.babelrc` seems to have fixed the issue. Thank you, @BelminBedak!

Comment: Okay, I'll add it as answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move your Babel related configurations from `webpack.config.js` file to separated `.babelrc` file in the project root.

Your newly created `.babelrc` file should looks like this

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

More info here: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/